# How to choose lang using session in laravel 5

Tags: laravel

How I should add choosing lang globally (using session).
I want to for example, change language from en to br, and I don't want to doing like this: "domin.com/en" but I want to do like this: domain.com (without en)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an ideal situation for middleware:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Session;

class SetLanguage {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        app()->setLocale(Session::get('language', 'en'));

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Give your users a little interface to set their session's language and you're all set.

Comment: How use middleware for all controlers?

Comment: @JędrzejBabiarz Add it to `app/Http/Kernel.php`'s `$middleware` array.